# how to use custom SSLSocketFactory class with org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl

Tags: spring, email, ssl, jakarta-mail

I need to use custom SSLFactory class to avoid problems with selfsigned certificates on mail server. I'm trying to use next configuration and it works just fine for gmail. But if I switch to my mail server it doesn't work any more and in wireshark I find errors **TLSv1 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Certificate Unknown)**. I tried to set custom sslfactory (replacing **javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory**), but it looks like that this change doesn't affect **JavaMailSenderImpl's** behaviour.

Mail server supports smtps protocol and requires authentication.

```
<bean id="userAuthorizationManager" class="com.mypackage.manage.SimpleUserAuthorizationManagerImpl">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
    <property name="from" value="address" />
    <property name="authorizationAddress" value="some text" />
    <property name="subject" value="some text" />
</bean>

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="465" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="protocol" value="smtps" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout">5000</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.sendpartial">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.userset">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.isSecure">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.requiresAuthentication">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>
            resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you need anything else I'll gladly provide it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Tiho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found a solution. I made an error.

Instead of **stmps** I used **smtp** in key names for properties while I used **smtps** as a protocol as you can see in my question.

Regards,
Tiho